# Correct way to write jQuery functions in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

I'm working with an AJAX based Wordpress template (custom), but I'm having some issues getting jQuery to play nicely.

I've enqueued everything (in the right order) and to an extent it does work, but I find myself having to write `jQuery('...` as oppose to the shorthand `$(...` every time I want to add a new script snippet. Am I doing something wrong? Please see my (slimmed down) custom JS file below;

```
function customThemeFunctions(){
    var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();
    jQuery('.full-height').css({'height' : windowHeight - 60});
    jQuery('.full-height-min').css({'min-height' : windowHeight - 60});
}

jQuery( document ).ready(function($){
    customThemeFunctions();
});

jQuery( document ).ajaxSuccess(function($){
    customThemeFunctions();
});
```

Comment: See [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments, this kind of error is caused by the fact that WordPress loads jquery in [noconflict mode](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/). The most common workaround is to wrap all functions in your script file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  ... scripts ... }
```

Another, more risky option is to switch off noconflict mode by starting the script file with this:

```
$ = jQuery.noConflict();
```